# wkhtmltopdf shrinks the input, which was fine in the older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

We use `wkhtmltopdf` to generate PDF from html and when upgraded from `0.12.3` to `0.12.6`, we noticed that the PDFs generated were in different resolutions.
Unfortunately, the `viewport-size`, or `dpi` did not help in fixing the problem.

Tried to downgrade to older version, but that's a crude way to go deprecated soon. So, `dpi` / `viewport-size` seems to have also failed us.
Finally, found `zoom` and adjusted the level to `1.25-1.3` times. I know this is never going to help across the different kinds of PDFs that are generated.

Any help here will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, after `0.12.4` version, `wkhtmltopdf` auto computes resolution for the pdf based on the dpi and web-driver.
To get back to the legacy pdf export, we need to use `--disable-smart-shrinking`.
ref: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/5056